# How do I use composition root DI with my view model construction and navigation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I'm writing a new WPF application and am using dependency injection. I've gone for a composition root so all my mappings between concrete types and interfaces is done in one place. I have two main questions:

1) Should the view models also be interfaces which are injected into the views? Advantages/disadvantages of this?

2) More importantly, where do the views get created and how do I achieve navigation when operating within this framework? For example, if Page A wants to push to page B via a "Go" button, where does PageB get constructed and where does ViewModelB (for pageB) get constructed and attached?

Comment: Have a look at the prism framework: https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/. It supports navigation and integrates with DI

Comment: What Framework? Have you heard about DataTemplates? ViewModels have already an Interface called `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you're doing MVVM right.